# Same message different nonce but similarities in r value of the signatures(r,s)

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, secp256k1

I'm studying a case where when i sign a same message with the same private key and a different nonce, i sometimes get signatures (r,s) where r values share some similarities (same numbers at the same indexes).

```
import ecdsa
import random
import sys
import math
from Crypto.Util.number import bytes_to_long
from ecdsa.numbertheory import inverse_mod
from Crypto.Hash import keccak

G = ecdsa.SECP256k1.generator
order = G.order()
priv1 = random.randrange(1,order)
 
Public_key = ecdsa.ecdsa.Public_key(G, G * priv1)
x1 = ecdsa.ecdsa.Private_key(Public_key, priv1)
k = random.randrange(1, 2**256)
k2 = random.randrange(1, 2**256)

msg1="testmessage one"
msg2="testmessage one"
    
h1 = int(keccak.new(data=msg1.encode(), digest_bits=256).hexdigest(), 16)
h2 = int(keccak.new(data=msg2.encode(), digest_bits=256).hexdigest(), 16)
a=101
b=44000


sig1 = x1.sign(h1, k)
sig2 = x1.sign(h2, k2)

r1,s1 = sig1.r,sig1.s
r2,s2 = sig2.r,sig2.s
```

for example here:

```
# r1: 78396664957968173303831259867144183331575644953624330443916619664823880076393
# r2: 72481257930359216601831910032528761795385061884841340241207919154214132347075
```

or

```
61906302142341328297806949441029581290248179645537018267214475508658072484184
61709238507240063345033283034280642403053119228497683727238078668394432174076
```

is this something to worry about?

Comment: Can you convert this numbers into bits and then count the matching 1s and 0s and compare to expected values, and do this million times? There is always lucky guesses.

Comment: is this a nice way to say that my question was stupid?

Comment: What you do is a more formally called distinguisher for ECDSA, in order to show that you need lots of lots of test. A single case can be lucky. I can't say stupid, I can only say that you were need more analysis beforehand since eyes can be deceiving.

Comment: This is the x-or of the two outputs; 10110011100010010101100011111010101011001111011110000111001111101001101101101100110010010101111011100000001100101000001111010000100001111010000101011100000001110111100010101001010111111111111001100011110110001110111011110111000001100110111010100100 What can you see?